# How to handle arena equipment in 1.7.10 so it can't be taken away by players?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Using 1.7.10 version, I want to create a PvP/PvE arena.
I want players to be able to get free equipment to play with, however, I don't want them to be able to carry this equipment home, because it will break the economy. Neither do I want to limit the total amount of times they can get the equipment nor players to be able to get advantage of "unauthorized" equipment that they carry *from* home.

The most straight-forward way to handle this is to have some large chests and/or an Ender Chest at the entrance, and have the players step onto a pressure plate that triggers a command block wiping their inventory each time they leave the arena (the passage is very narrow). If enough signs are put, players will understand how it works and not lose their things. Arena equipment is given inside, by activating another command block. I have seen this working on another server, but if a player fails to understand that his inventory is going to get wiped, he will lose his things. Also his things may get stolen from the chests if he doesn't use the Ender Chest -- which I don't want.

**Is there any way, probably through plugins/mods, to replace player's inventory with something else to automatically restore it later?**

Comment: Can you put your arena on a separate server instance and merge them with bungeecord?

Comment: @Zoredache I don't really want this, but if you know how to do it, may you please share your solution as an answer?

Comment: Why are you using 1.7.10? That is an extremely old version.

Comment: @Okx My target audience likes it when there are lots of mods&plugins -- they are still playing 1.6.4, BTW. There isn't really much new in the later versions, except for some mods not being present because each update makes them incompatible. I personally don't like changes made in 1.8 and 1.9.

Comment: just how are people playing on 1.7.10 still... just how... mods and plugins drop support for old versions and you'll get loads of new mods and plugins and features etc on newer versions. Most mods are on version 1.10.2 right now.

Comment: I remind you again that I don't like changes of the newer versions. Please, don't change the topic -- I need a possible solution that allows to somehow save player's inventory and then restore.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy
I assume that you are looking for a mod or plugin, based on your specifications. So... an external server script counts as a modification, right? I can't go too in-depth as this isn't Stack Overflow, but if you do some searching and get training, you could create something of your own that you can show to others and boast. The script will, use classes and or variables to store the item values and such. So and so. Should this be an answer?

Comment: @ghostwalker13 Hmm. I know almost nothing about coding for Minecraft, but if you provide an instruction for this solution, or links where I may find the instruction, I will likely accept it. Anything that works will be accepted. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution to your problem, although not specifically **my solution**. Here it is.
[Multiverse-Inventories](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/multiverse-inventories?page=39#c225)<sup>Minecraft Version Not Confirmed</sup> and [Per World Inventories](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/per-world-inventory.4482/)<sup>Minecraft Version Confirmed 1.8 1.9 1.10 1.11</sup> .

The idea behind the two is that, if you have separate 'worlds'/realms for different activities such as mining and or marketing so and so, you will be able to maintain players' inventories between them all. So a Trading Inv. for a Trading World<sup>< Example</sup> and a Mining Inv. for the Mining World<sup>< Example</sup> and so-on...

They're both relatively easy to use and branches off-of [Bukkit](https://bukkit.org/) / [Spigot](https://www.spigotmc.org/) and have attached instructions.
(Keep in mind that 'Multiverse-Inventories' is no longer maintained and wil not receive updates, the creators have included a note in their post)
The APIs are a peach too! That is... if you're into programming like me :happy_face: .
You'll find that one of them, fits your needs.

Good Luck.

**Note:** I could not find anything, from my time doing searches, about 1.7.10 mods/plugins that helped with this, sorry. But if you feel like upgrading to a higher Minecraft Version, you'll find that this became a whole lot more useful. :smiley_face:

Comment: Hmm. That's an awesome thing. Can I use them for only some worlds? For example, you only have your normal inventory temporarly confiscated when you enter the arena, but other planes are untouched? Because I want players to be able to go mining in a different plane and carry their things, or just go to a different plane that is a different plane by RP.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy
Certainly. But I'll be talking about 'Per World Inventories', as it is regularly maintained and up to date. They are configurable in the **setup.yml** file that would be used. If you look at the video on the PWI-page (0:45) our spectator talks about Converting from MVI to PWI, the PWI permissions/abilities and so and so. But it's certain that you'll be able to designate what gets taken away and what gets given. In specific worlds.